# Python sklearn sparse pca: something wrong while computing variance of PCs

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca, variance

I am trying to compute principal components of n*p matrix X using the [sklearn.decomposition.SparsePCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.SparsePCA.html).

The n indicates the number of samples and the p indicates the number of features.

Then I follow the way in this paper(https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/reading/papers/sparsepc.pdf) to compute the adjusted variance of each principal components.

As it in the paper, I use QR decomposition to the modified PCs, and compute adjusted variance by `(R[j][j])^2`.

But the results( variance of modified PCs ) are not monotone decreasing. As following, variance of 3rd PC is larger than the one of 2nd PC:

variance of PCs:

```
[ 1.          0.59902395  0.64761414  0.64657846  0.50450935  0.59905398 0.45242596  0.42738204]
```

variance_ratio of PCs:

```
[ 0.20506141  0.1228367   0.13280067  0.13258829  0.1034554   0.12284286
  0.09277511  0.08763956]
```

Is it because the output of sklearn.decomposition.SparsePCA.transform whithout order of the PCs, or something wrong with my codes?

I would appreciate it if someone could solve my problem.

The following is my code:

```
    # read n*p matrix X( n = 1043, p = 20 )
    cluster_data = input_cluster_data('./data/km_results_1.csv')

    # train spca
    model = decomposition.SparsePCA( n_components=8 )
    model.fit( cluster_data )
    cluster_data_projection = model.transform( cluster_data )

    # QR decomposition of modified PCs
    cluster_data_projection_qr = np.linalg.qr( cluster_data_projection )
    q = cluster_data_projection_qr[0]
    r = cluster_data_projection_qr[1]

    # compute adjusted variance
    variance = []
    for i in range(8):
        variance.append( np.square(r[i][i]) )

    variance = np.array(variance)


    # compute variance_ratio
    sum = np.sum( variance )
    variance_ratio = variance / sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.trace(np.dot(R.T,R))` or `np.trace(np.dot(R,R.T))`, depending how you organize your data.

Comment: I guess is `np.diag` instead of `np.trace`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the fact that PCs obtained by Elastic net regression (the method used in scikit learn) are not uncorrelated nor orthogonal, and therefore might not have the same properties as PCs from PCA